# Boots to terminal

Tags: 12.04, boot, command-line, 32-bit

I had a system running 10.04, I think. I upgraded it to 11.04, everything was fine. But then when I upgraded it further to 11.10, the system would only boot to a terminal, no desktop like before.

I installed 12.04 on it instead, keeping `/home` which was on another partition... but it's still booting to terminal. I believe there may be some bad configuration files left over that are causing this.

Looking at other similar issues, I looked for `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` but it doesn't exist. `startx` says it isn't installed. Installing `nvidia-current` didn't help (has GF 6600 GT video card). Alt+F7 shows a blank screen.

I used the alternate installer, and didn't select any of the optional packages it prompts during installation. Should I have?

How do I get it to boot to desktop like normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed using the normal desktop install instead of alternate and it's working. Don't know what was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install xorg
```

Comment: Having done that, `startx` complains that `Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)`, and also for `"nv"`. Ctrl+Alt+F7 shows a terminal with a slightly different font, but it doesn't respond to keyboard input (can't type on it).

Comment: It looks something similar: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1804394

Comment: Actually I can type on that terminal, needed to hover cursor over it first. Installing `nvidia-current` gets rid of the error failing to load `"nvidia"`, but `"nv"` still persists. That linked thread seem to be about a `module-specific error` whereas mine is `module does not exist`.

Answer (score 0):

Your graphics card seems to have nvidia optimus technology which is not implemented for Linux.

First of all you should delete Xorg.conf by using `# rm /etc/X11/Xorg.conf` then install `Bumbleebee` (assuming that you had installed `nvidia-current`) to switch from your onboard graphics card.

If you want to make use of your `nvidia card` use the following command to start an application

```
  $ optirun <command>
```

Comment: Are you sure? Mind you, 11.04 and prior worked perfectly fine on this video card.